# Selenium - Find all elements and use WebDriverWait with for loop

Tags: python, selenium

I have some problems with Selenium where I am trying to find all elements and then try to use WebDriverWait:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                    "//*[contains(text(), 'Hello')]")))
getAllErrors = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "message")))

for productErrors in getAllErrors:

    if 'Sad moments' in productErrors.text:

        totalProduct = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((productErrors.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='number']"))))

        #How to call productErrors and to use WebDriverWait with it?
```

I wonder how to use the for loop data and use WebDriverWait with the for loop varaiable?

Basically something like

```
for productErrors in getAllErrors:

    WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((productErrors.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='number']")))) 
    #Use productErrors For loop and find the xpath from productErrors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `presence_of` for already located element, but you can use `visibility_of`

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
for productErrors in getAllErrors:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of(productErrors.find_element_by_xpath("./following-sibling::div//input[@type='number']")))
```

Don't forget to add `.` to the `xpath` for context search. You can also declare `WebDriverWait(browser, 5)` one time and use it everywhere.

Comment: You can use `presence_of_element_located` here as well.

Comment: @Murthi `presence_of_element_located` receive `By` as parameter, not `WebElement`.

Comment: Is it possible to do `wait = WebDriverWait(productErrors, 5)` instead of browser?

Comment: @Thrillofit86 No, `WebDriverWait` `__init__` expects `WebDriver`. Why? what are trying to do by doing that?

Comment: I tried to run your code which gave me an error of no such elemen: Unable to locate element. While I tried to change the code to `WebDriverWait(productErrors, 5).until(
                            EC.presence_of_element_located(((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='number']")))).get_attribute(
                            'value')` and that seemed to work. To change `browser` to `productErrors`

Comment: @Thrillofit86 Python is not strong typing language, so although `WebDriverWait` expect `WebDriver` (you can see it in the `__init__' comments`:  `- driver - Instance of WebDriver (Ie, Firefox, Chrome or Remote)`) , there is no check to see if it's really  a `WebDriver`. You can locate a `WebElement` with another `WebElement` so this works. It wouldn't work in strong typing languages like Java.

Comment: I see. Its pretty odd that it works but as you say. It could be the strong typing but however. I do think something is wrong with ur code when I am trying to apply it.  The reason I do have the for loop in the first place is that there is 3x same type of messages with the same class. So my idea was to do a for loop where I enter each `message` by using for loop and then use your method to click but when I do that it says there is no such element like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203103/discussion-between-guy-and-thrillofit86).